# How can I clear the Warnings sections of the error list In VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, wcag

Specifically, once I get the WCAG Anaylsis warnings for a website into my warnings window I can't get rid of them, until I close down studio. When building another project in the same solution they stay there.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across this question yesterday looking for an easy answer.  While closing the solution works for me, and then rebuilding only the solution I want to see warnings on, I found that doing a "Clean Solution" (right-click solution, select "Clean Solution") will clear the Error List pane (including warnings).

Comment: This is a pretty heavyweight solution -- it also deletes all compiled assemblies, so if you do this you'll need to rebuild everything. For large solutions, this can be a problem.

Answer (score 6):

Unload/Reload project

I regularly get stubborn errors that do not clear (in the VS2010 Error List with MS Ajax Minifier).  I found that Unloading and Reloading the project clears the errors; **this works more easily than closing and re-opening the solution**.  This is less than ideal, but is the best solution I've found to work around the buggy interaction between VS2010 and MS Ajax Minifier.

Error   1
The Microsoft Ajax Minifier does not have permission to write to Content\ ... .min.css

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2015 and SSRS, I had the same issue with stubborn warnings, and this was the only solution that worked.

Answer (score 4):

Close all open documents and rebuild the solution to get rid of those warnings. I have also that problem on webprojects and WCAG-varnings, but they disapear when Im doing a rebuild.

Comment: Tried it didn't work. Rebuilt on a library and the unrelated warnings stayed there.

Comment: I believe so, I'll double check in a moment but I'm pretty sure I did it:
- Open solution in studio
- Build Website
- Build Library

When I'm at a suitable juncture again I'll give it another go to be 100%

Comment: Usually I check for accessibility on one page at a time to avoid this. It may be tedious, but it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread but was having the same problem.  I found that the warnings would dissapear by doing the following:

1. Closing the documents in question
2. Clicking on the Output tab
3. Rebuild the application

Now when you click back on the Error List tab and look at warnings, they should be reset.

Answer (score 0):

You can permanently disable warnings:

```
website -> property pages -> accessibility -> uncheck "show warnings"
```

Otherwise just close all files

```
window -> close all documents
```

Answer (score 0):

Just close Visual Studio and re-open?

Answer (score -1):

Just click on the "Warnings" button at the top of the window to hide them.

Comment: If I hide them, they're still there. For example if I run stylecop on a  code library, the WCAG warnings are still there but entwined with the stylecop ones I actually care about.